# C++ Custom exception is throwing runtime error instead of itself in boost unit test

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I have some custom exceptions: a base which inherits from `std::runtime_exception`, and another which inherits from the base.

**The base:**

```
class Customexception : public std::runtime_error
{
  public:
  // Error message constructor.
  explicit Customexception(const std::string err);

  // Destructor
  virtual ~Customexception() throw();

  protected:
  private:
};

Customexception::Customexception(std::string err)
    :
    std::runtime_error(err)
{
}

Customexception::~Customexception() throw()
{
}
```

**The derived exception:**

```
class Derivedexception : public Customexception
{
  public:
  // Error message constructor.
  explicit Derivedexception(std::string const err);

  // Destructor
  virtual ~Derivedexception() throw();

  protected:
  private:
};

Derivedexception::Derivedexception(std::string const err)
    :
    Customexception(err)
{
}

Derivedexception::~Derivedexception() throw()
{
}
```

**And somewhere in the main program:**

```
if (/* condition */)
{
  throw Derivedexception("Bad things have happened");
}
```

But in the boost unit test it says that the `std::runtime_error` exception is thrown! And not the `Derivedexception`! The `std::runtime_error` even has a `what()` method which is equal to `Bad things have happened`, and so it seems that `std::runtime_error` is created and not `Derivedexception`!

I.e. I am simply doing this in the unit test:

```
  BOOST_CHECK_THROW(/* some bad stuff here */, Derivedexception);
```

And the test fails and it says that `error exception Derivedexception is expected`.

Any idea why it is doing this? I.e. I explicitly throw `Derivedexception` yet it throws `runtime_exception`!

EDIT: BUMP, HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPP!!!